# Match prop values to lookup list with new (pretty) values

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm using react and lodash. I have a prop type `{props.value}` that returns the result of `"ThisIsFoo"` and other results such as `"ThisIsBar"`. I want to be able to map these results to elegantly display the output as `"This is foo"`. Some sort of look up array will do the trick where I can list all the possible outcomes.
e.g.

```
    var KeyMap = {
        ThisIsFoo : "This is foo",
        ThisIsBar : "This is Bar",
        anotherOutcomeHere: "Another outcome here"
    };
```

Ideally I want to get lodash to look at {props.value} match them to the key is it exists then output with its replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var KeyMap = {
        slowFit : "Slow Fit",
        fastFit : "Fast Fit",
        slowUnfit : "Slow Unfit",
        fastUnfit : "Fast Unfit",

    };

const str = props.label.replace(/slowFit|fastFit|slowUnfit|fastUnfit/gi, function(matched){
  return KeyMap[matched];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create the keyMap from the values and then you can just match by the key:

```js
var data = ["This is foo", "This is Bar", "Another outcome here"]

var keyMap = _.reduce(data, (r,c) => Object.assign(r, {[c.replace(/ /g, "")]: c}), {})

console.log("KeyMap: ", keyMap)
console.log(keyMap['ThisisBar'])
console.log(keyMap['Thisisfoo'])

// In your casse you would just display {keyMap[props.value]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```